# Einstein Analytics - Rest API start job from API

Tags: rest-api, einstein-analytics, analytics

I'm trying to run a dataflowjob from API using Patch Method

`/services/data/v43.0/wave/dataflowjobs/03Cf4000001pShyEAE`

```
{
    "dataflowId": "02Kf40000005wyAEAQ"
    "command": "start"
}
```

I'm receiving this error :

```
errorCode: 306
message: Invalid job command
```

Answer (score 0):

Take the Id out of the endpoint url.
The endpoint should be:  **/services/data/v43.0/wave/dataflowjobs**